# Selenium - Page Object Model - Good way to identify page during a dynamic flow

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, test-design, page-object-pattern

My application has a possible flow to get all info from the user, where at max might consist of pages in the order **A->B->C->D->E->F**, each page asking for different info until we get to an end Summary Page. In reality though you generally only see a subset of the pages depending on what information already exists in the DB for your item, or depending on the answers you give to specific questions, so you could end up with flows more like **A->B->D->F, A->B->F, A->E->F**, etc.

I am using Selenium (Java), and trying to follow Page Object Model best practices. All of my page objects verify they are loaded when I create them, and when I perform an action that moves to a new page, I create and return that new page.

The problem here is that when we continue from one page to the next, we can't guarantee which page we will see, A could expect B or E for example. Since some of the information that determines what page we see next is external to the application, I can't just create simple "if we chose X, return page B, if Y return E" logic trees to determine what page to return.

My initial thought on how to handle this is to basically just to identify what page we are currently looking at, using a Utility or a method on a common Parent page object. This strategy doesn't sit right with me though because it goes against good design practices that I've been told to follow, because it creates additional coupling between classes, requires parents to know what classes implement them, etc.

It is also somewhat messy because there is not a single common way to identify any individual page: Some pages share the same URL, some pages share the same title, others have no title at all, etc. So I can't just have a single <String,Page> mapping and .get() based on an identifier. So each page (or at least several distinct groups of page types) will have to use their own unique logic to identify whether the page we're looking at matches.

This seems like something that isn't really "unique" though, I feel like most complicated websites will have at least a few activity flows that follow different page sequences. I have not had any luck finding any results when trying to web search for any common solutions to this issue though.

Does anyone have some good go-to answers on how you handle this kind of situation? Or am I just going to have to bite the bullet and force in some "bad design"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some verification that you are on the correct page, you can add a div on each page with a unique identifier.
Then have a factory that looks for this identifier and creates the correct object.

```
<div page-name="Page A" />
<div page-name="Page B" />
...
```

Test:

```
val pageA = (PageA) PageGenerator.generate(driver);
pageA.doSomething();
val pageB = (PageB) PageGenerator.generate(driver);
pageB.doSomethingElse();
```

Factory:

```
class PageGenerator {

public static Page generator(Driver driver) {
   switch(GenericPage.getPageName(driver)){
      case "Page A": return new PageA(driver);
      case "Page B": return new PageB(driver);
      ...
   }
 }

}
```

Generic Page:

class GenericPage {

```
public static Page getPageName(Driver driver) {
   return driver.findElement(pageNameLocator).text();
 }

}
```

In this case, if you end up on the wrong page, a runtime error on the test will show you this problem, because the type conversion won't work.

But if you simply want to generate the page objects, **your tests should know
what page you are supposed to be in** (otherwise you won't have reliable tests).

In this case, you can simply generate the page objects in your test, instead of reliaing in :

```
val pageA = new PageA(driver);
pageA.doSomething();
val pageB = new PageB(driver);
pageB.doSomethingElse();
```